# why is it possible to set $GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['logo'] in typo3conf/extTables.php, but not in typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

just out of curiosity: 
As you all might or might know, it is possible to set a custom BE logo with  `$GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']['logo'] = '../fileadmin/mylogo.png';` in *typo3conf/extTables.php*.

This behavior is working since old v4.x times.
But I just read that extTables will be deprecated in v8.x.
I tried to find a simple solution to this (one that keeps that one-line simplicity and does NOT require me to create&install an extension!)

I moved this line to *typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php*, 
but it does not work from there.

Why?

What would be necessary to make this line work within typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TYPO3 8.x you'll be able to change a backend logo via `EXT:backend`, so you should stick to that approach. Read more in [release notes](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8-dev/Changelog/8.0/Feature-74109-SetTheAlternativeBackendLogoViaExtensionManager.html).

UPDATE.
To answer your question, why `TBE_STYLES` defined in AdditionalConfiguration are ignored: take a look at `unsetReservedGlobalVariables()` [method](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php#L758-L770) from `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap` class. It is executed after all the configuration is initialized (Local and Additional are merged and populated) and explicitly calls `unset($GLOBALS['TBE_STYLES']);`.

Comment: This seems like a viable one-line solution to me. Will research int othis further and update here accordingly.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question, why TBE_STYLES has no effect in AdditionalConfiguration...

Comment: @mtness, please check _UPDATE_ section of my answer.

Comment: wow, thankyou, that nails it completely! didin't know of these methods yet! Thank you very much.